# Access a domain's local storage directly from extension's background script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I wish to retrieve a value stored in a domain's local storage from my extension's background script. Note this is accessing a domain's local storage, not the extension's local storage.

So I think it would be something similar to getting it from window.localStorage

My extension has permission to the domain in question.

I am able to access the domain's cookie like this:

```
let cookie = await chrome.cookies.get({ 'url': 'https://example.com', 'name': 'access_token' });
```

But so far I have been unable to figure out how to access the local storage in a similar manner as I do the cookie.

I think I can execute a content script domain's page to retrieve the data I want and send it back to the background page, but that is more complicated and I would prefer to access it directly as I do the cookie.

Comment: I don't think you can access it directly. As shown in the linked question, use the `sendMessage` API to send it from the content script to the background script.

Comment: You'll have to declare a [temporary content script](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#method-registerContentScripts) with `allFrames:true`, create the [offscreen document](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/), inside which add an iframe for the site, then read localStorage and send a message to the background script. The only other way is `chrome.debugger`, but it shows a global warning every time it's used.

Comment: I guess the answer to my question is "you can't". The linked to question describes the method one must use instead, but it does not really answer my question and is not a duplicate.